# How to find data similarities in a single column in R ?

Tags: r

A product column contains data which are very similar to each other ? For example Fish Oil capsule
Fish Oil Capsule 1x30
Fish Oil Caps

All are same data but I want to make them one as "Fish Oil Caps" for better analysis.

There are approx 400 such records with different product.
I would have used 'jaccard','jw' distance method using Stringdist but it is very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Using stringdistmatrix function on 400 random strings with length=15, user time is=0.12 secs.

```
strings<-stringi::stri_rand_strings(400, 15)
system.time(stringdistmatrix(strings, strings,method = "jw"))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.12    0.01    0.05
```